# select max date with order by

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have this linq query

```
var additivesTimesTamps = (from q in Uow.UserAdditionStamps.Data
                                       group q.UserId by new
                                       {
                                           q.UserId,
                                           q.TimeStamp
                                       } into qq
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           UID = qq.Key.UserId,
                                           TimeStamp = qq.Key.TimeStamp
                                       }).ToList();
```

and it selects this:

```
1   2013-01-31 18:08:19.847 
29  2013-01-04 16:28:52.557
29  2013-01-05 16:28:52.557
```

How can I group that to select only 1 date per UserId? t-sql simply is this:

```
select userid as uId, max([timestamp]) as ts 
from UserAdditionStamp 
group by UserId
```

That t-sql code is exactly what i need but at linq

Comment: Isn't it is better & first to write direct query instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change groupby to group only on `UserId` and then Select Max `TimeStamp` for that group like:

```
group q by  q.UserId into qq
                     select new
                     {
                         UID = qq.Key,
                         TimeStamp = qq.Max(x=>x.TimeStamp)
                     })
```

Comment: You don't need a anonymous object if you are grouping by one item.

Comment: Also, it should rather be `group q by  q.UserId`

Comment: Now works thanks for answer and thank you guys for correction